# Filtering rows with some NaNs in DFs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframes with many rows, and some values are NaNs.
For example -

```
index  col1     col2    col3
0       1.0     NaN     3.0  
1       NaN     4.0     NaN  
3       1.0     5.0     NaN
```

**I would like to filter the DF and return only the rows with 2+ values.**
The number should be configurable.
The resulted DF will be -

```
index  col1     col2    col3
0       1.0     NaN     3.0  
3       1.0     5.0     NaN
```

Any idea how can I achieve this result? I've tried creating new column but it doesn't seem the right way.

Thanks!
Code to create the DF:

```
d = {'col1': [1, None, 1], 'col2': [None, 4, 5], 'col3': [3, None, None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dropna()` set the threshold to be 2 `thresh=2`, and perform operation along the rows `axis=0`:

```
res = df.dropna(thresh=2,axis=0)

res 
   col1  col2  col3
0  1.00   NaN  3.00
2  1.00  5.00   NaN
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Answer (score -1):

You can delete the 2nd row by using the `drop()` method.

```py
ax = df.drop([1])
print(ax)
```